# How do I inject a named dependency into a constructor with unity 5.0.0?

Tags: c#, asp.net, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, unity-container

I have a named dependency that I previously injected like this:

```
    public Data([Dependency("FormMapper")] IMapper formMapper)
    {
         ...
    }
```

With the upgrade to Unity 5.0 this no longer works. How do I inject it with the updated Unity API?

Comment: Unity is dead, why use it any longer...

Comment: well.. If you have a large code base you may not have the option to choose. This happens to be the case for me

Comment: @Legends Why should unity be dead? It has just a new owner.

Comment: I used it for years, but if you look at the new release v5, you can read that they were inactive for years. `After few years of inactivity we are finally updating Unity library.` So this is some kind of resurrection here :D.  There are better supported libraries out there, Structuremap, Ninject, etc...

Comment: A resurrection without any documentation...as good as dead.